How to skip tasks, if vault-password is not set?
A playbook of ours installs a private key-file among other things:
- name: Install the deploy key
  copy:
    src: gitkey
    dest: ~/.ssh/gitkey
    mode: 0400

The key rarely changes, and we rarely add new servers.
The key is encrypted with vault and, if we don't specify the password (through one of the many methods), the task fails:
fatal: [xxxx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "A vault password or secret must be specified to decrypt .../playbooks/roles/make-from-git/files/gitkey"}

I'd like for this task to simply be skipped, if there is no password available at runtime. How would I do that?

IMO, the only option is Error handling in playbooks. I'd recommend block/rescue.

As far as I know, it is not possible to determine at runtime whether a vault password has been provided to the playbook.
However, you can use an extra variable (--extra-vars) to control task execution:
playbook.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Install the deploy key
      copy:
        src: gitkey
        dest: ~/.ssh/gitkey
        mode: "0400"
      when: 'install_key | d(false) | bool'

To enable the taks, you can run the playbook with this option:
ansible-playbook -i HOST, playbook.yml -e 'install_key=true' --ask-vault-password

To skip the task, either set the variable to false or omit it:
ansible-playbook -i HOST, playbook.yml -e 'install_key=false'
ansible-playbook -i HOST, playbook.yml


Use when: my_flag | d(false) | bool. It's simpler and bool converts strings provided by --extra-vars.

Use Handling errors with blocks.

lookup

For example, given the encrypted file
shell> ansible-vault view files/gitkey
my secret git key

Put the task into a block and clear the host's errors if the task fails
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - block:

        - copy:
            dest: /tmp/gitkey
            content: |
              {{ lookup('file', 'files/gitkey') }}
            mode: "0400"

      rescue:

        - meta: clear_host_errors

If the vault secret is available you get the file
shell> cat /tmp/gitkey 
my secret git key

Otherwise, the failed task will be rescued
TASK [copy] *********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: The 'file' lookup had an issue accessing the file 'files/gitkey'. Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found

TASK [meta] *********************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0



vars

You can't use the automatic decryption of vars because this doesn't happen in tasks. Hence, this can't be rescued. For example, given the encrypted file
shell> ansible-vault view group_vars/all/gitkey
gitkey: my secret git key

If the vault secret is available the below play creates the same file as the lookup example
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - block:

        - copy:
            dest: /tmp/gitkey
            content: |
              {{ gitkey }}
            mode: "0400"

      rescue:

        - meta: clear_host_errors

Otherwise, the play will fail right at the beginning because the vars can't be decrypted
shell> ansible-playbook pb4.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************
ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found


Note: The lookup option is more secure because the decrypted value is available only in the scope of a single task. The secrets are available in the scope of a play if you put them into the vars.

Q: Distinguish the failure due to the key being unknown from others: key being invalid, file being corrupted, destination permissions preventing the file update, etc.
A: See Handling errors with blocks. The rescue section provides you with the variable ansible_failed_result. For example,
      rescue:

        - debug:
            var: ansible_failed_result
        - meta: clear_host_errors

gives if the vault secret is missing
  ...Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found

if the file is missing you'll see
  ...file not found, use -vvvvv to see paths searched

Feel free to test more. Optionally, take a look at the source.

The block/rescue method does not skip the task, it just handles the failure, doesn't it? I imagine, a similar effect could be achieved with a clever failed_when condition too. But that's not quite, what I'm looking for...

Yes, as I said yesterday. The error handling is the only option.

If the error-handling is the only option, it needs to distinguish the failure due to key being unknown from others: key being invalid, file being corrupted, destination permissions preventing the file update, etc. Those other failures should not be ignored... Is that possible? Could you update the answer to that effect, so I can "accept" it? Thank you!

@VladimirBotka it's not the only one, as you could see in my example. Yes, it wouldn't work when the vault password is set via --ask-vault-password, but the OP didn't set any constraints on this, so I still consider it a valid option.

Ansible Vault password is not available at runtime. But there is a trick - if you define the vault password in a secret file and use its path as the ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE Ansible environment variable, you can build logic based on its value:
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    encrypted_string: vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT; 1.1; AES256
      35663436646433643630656434336330353936653065     356336316237393439613665383938363933
      65386135653037633032636638316535383632623234303208653636623936306236643939373734
      64303136306335336434343166383431623663306334306266353431373038306539343465643564
      3966343263316639300a663433353765333765633234366561393864323535383730646233643039
      3764
  tasks:
    - name: Show me the secret
      debug:
        var: encrypted_string
      vars:
        secret: "{{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE') }}"
      when: secret is defined and secret

You can test this example using 12345 as the vault password:
cat 12345 > vault_password
export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=vault_password
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml

